# Sending request/accept notification for friendship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a mutual friendship model, where one user requests a friendship and creates a model with `user_id` of current_user and `friend_id` of the friend.

Then the friend accepts it and creates another model of the inverse.

Now I am trying to send notification upon both cases. The problem is that @friend (current_user as well) in my code seems to be nil or otherwise just not working.

```
  def notify_friend_request
    @friend = params[:friend]
    @url  = 'http://localhost:3000'
    @first_name = @friend.first_name
    @last_name = @friend.last_name
    @email = @friend.email
    @sent_user = current_user
    @sent_user_first_name = @sent_user.first_name
    @sent_user_last_name = @sent_user.last_name
    
    mail(to: @email,
         subject: 'You have a new friend request!')
```

What could be wrong? I'd really appreciate help.

My friendship controller, create method is below. Upon request or acceptance the appropriate mailer method seems to be called (notify_friend_request vs. accept)

```
  def create
    @inviting_user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])
    if @friendship.save
      if @friend.friends.include? current_user
        UserMailer.with(friendship: @friendship).notify_friend_accept.deliver_later
      else 
        UserMailer.with(friendship: @friendship).notify_friend_request.deliver_later
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code. Posting a question really cleared up my head:

```
  def notify_friend_request
    @friendship = params[:friendship]
    @url  = 'http://localhost:3000'
    @first_name = User.find(@friendship.user_id).first_name
    @last_name = User.find(@friendship.user_id).last_name
    @sent_user = User.find(@friendship.friend_id)
    @sent_user_first_name = @sent_user.first_name
    @sent_user_last_name = @sent_user.last_name
    @email = @sent_user.email
    
    mail(to: @email,
         subject: 'You have a new friend request!')
  end
```